# How to use async and await in NGRX effect of angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am working with NGRX (State Management) in angular 11.

I am showing a tenant list on component load. Using NGRX effect and in effect i am requesting http call through service.

**This is my effect**

```
@Injectable()
export class TenantsListEffects {
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private tenantListService: 
TenantAdministrationService) { }


loadTenants$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(TenantsListActions.TenantsListActionTypes.LoadTenantsLists),

switchMap(
  
  ((action) => this.tenantListService.getAllTenantsUsingGET().pipe(

  map(tenants => { return new TenantsListActions.LoadTenantsListsSuccess({ 
  data: tenants }) }),
    catchError(err => of(new TenantsListActions.LoadTenantsListsFailure({ 
  error: err })))
    )
    )
   ))
   )
  }
```

**This is my tenantList.reducer.ts**

```
    export const tenantsListFeatureKey = 'tenantsListState';


    export interface tenantsListState {
     tenants: DisplayNameToTenantMappingResponse[],
     loading: boolean,
     error: string
    }

     export const initialState: tenantsListState = {
  tenants: [],
  loading: false,
  error: ''
};


export function reducer(state = initialState, action: TenantsListActions): tenantsListState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TenantsListActionTypes.LoadTenantsLists:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case TenantsListActionTypes.LoadTenantsListsSuccess:
      return {
        ...state,
        tenants: action.payload.data,
        loading:false,
        error: null
      }
    case TenantsListActionTypes.LoadTenantsListsFailure:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload.error,
        loading: false
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**This is my selector**

```
const getTenantsListState = createFeatureSelector<tenantsListState>('tenantsListState');

export const getTenants = createSelector(
    getTenantsListState,
    state => state.tenants
)

export const getError = createSelector(
    getTenantsListState,
    state => state.error
)
```

**This is my service**

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TenantAdministrationService {
public basePath: string ='';
constructor(private basePathService: BasePathService,private http: 
HttpClient) {
this.basePath = this.basePathService.selectEnv();
}

public 
getAllTenantsUsingGET():Observable<DisplayNameToTenantMappingResponse[]>{
let test =  this.http.get<Array<DisplayNameToTenantMappingResponse>> 
(`${this.basePath}/admin/tenant`);
console.log('get list ', test);

return test
}
```

**The problem is**

When i first called the service it retunes nothing and so it didn't store any thing in my ngrx store.
But after 2 to 3 second it returns tenant list and stored in the store as a state.

i Tried to make async function to my service call method but it cause error in Effect.

**So could some one help me how to handle this ....**

[image]

Comment: Please add real code, screenshots of code is no code.

Comment: hi I edited  with real code.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using a switchMap to call an async function, and after that I used a map to process the result from the async function. I'm using Angular 13 and NgRx 13.

My code:

```
  loadUser$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthEvent),
    concatLatestFrom( () => [
      this.store.select(getUid),
      this.store.select(getEmail)
    ]),
    switchMap( ([action, uid, email]) => this.service.loadUser(uid, email)),
    map( user => {
      console.log(user);
      switch (user.level) {
         ....
      }
    }),
    catchError( error => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(UnexpectedError());
    })    
  ));
```

I'm doing this:

```
  loadUser$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(...),
    concatLatestFrom(...),
    switchMap( () => this.service.anAsyncFuntion()),
    map(...),
    catchError(...)    
  ));
```

instead of this:

```
  loadUser$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(...),
    concatLatestFrom(...),
    switchMap( () => this.service.anAsyncFuntion()).pipe(
       map(...),
       catchError(...)
    )
  ));
```

I'm not using pipe to deal with the output from switchMap.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have things set up right, but I see an extra paren `(` after switchMap. Like this it should work.

```
loadTenants$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(TenantsListActions.TenantsListActionTypes.LoadTenantsLists),
  switchMap(action => this.tenantListService.getAllTenantsUsingGET().pipe(
    map(tenants => new TenantsListActions.LoadTenantsListsSuccess({ data: tenants }),
    catchError(err => of(new TenantsListActions.LoadTenantsListsFailure({ 
  error: err })))
  )
);
```

Keep in mind, your reducer needs to add the entities to state before your store selector will emit them.

```
const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(TenantsListActions.LoadTenantsListsSuccess, (state, { data }) => featureAdapter.setAll(data, {
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
  })),
  ...
);
```

Above I'm using an [entity adapter](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter) to add the entities to state.

Comment: i posted my tenant list reducer how can i modify my code to add entity adapter. i have read  the documentation but i didn't understand

Comment: what you're doing should also work. Did you remove the extra paren?

Comment: yes i removed the extra paren but the problem is still same

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem i used the state property loading and used it as an observable in my component. `

```
export interface tenantsListState {
     tenants: DisplayNameToTenantMappingResponse[],
     loading: boolean,
     error: string
    }
```

`

During the http call this becomes `loading = true;` and it triggered a spinner which stop the component loading until the http call is return back.